# Is there a simple way to get the first argument passed to Rspec's `describe`?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Suppose I have a test suite where I start by giving `describe` a constant:

```
describe SomeExcessivelyLong::And::Maybe::Namespaced::Classname do

  # Convenience reference for tests
  let(:klass) { SomeExcessivelyLong::And::Maybe::Namespaced::Classname }

end
```

Is there an existing method, like `subject` or something similar, that makes this `let(:klass)` redundant? How can I access the first value passed to `describe`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call `described_class` in your example so:

```
describe SomeExcessivelyLong::And::Maybe::Namespaced::Classname do
  it "should do something" do
    described_class.should be SomeExcessivelyLong::And::Maybe::Namespaced::Classname
  end
end
```

Comment: Perfect! To expand on this: `described_class` returns the actual class (not the string name) if `describe` was given one; if a string is given, like `describe "SomeClass"`, `described_class` returns `nil`.

Answer (score 5):

By default `subject` will be a new instance of the class in the describe block so you should be able call `subject.class` to get the class itself.

```
describe SomeExcessivelyLong::And::Maybe::Namespaced::Classname do
  it "should do something" do
    subject.class.should be_a SomeExcessivelyLong::And::Maybe::Namespaced::Classname
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice. However, the downside there is that you have to get a new instance first in order to work back to the class. In my case, the class being described has required arguments for its `initialize` method, so calling `subject` by itself gets `wrong number of arguments`.

Comment: True.  There must be a way to get to it, perhaps if you dig into the source looking around the 'subject' stuff it will become apparent...